# C# Mysql Does not update

Tags: c#, mysql

The Error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Default=0 WHERE Default=1 AND UserID=3' at line 1
```

For some reason its not working i don't really see an error with this code.

Am trying to update database to set the default 0 if its 1 by the userid as you can see

Thank you very much.

```
try
{
    using (
        MySqlCommand cmd =
            new MySqlCommand("UPDATE user_inventory SET Default=0 WHERE Default=1 AND UserID=@oid",
                MysqlHandler.DbConnection))
    {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oid", user.UserId);
            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Looks good so far. I guess its a typing error!? Could you execute `DESCRIBE user_inventory` and post the output?

Comment: I don't see any typing error with the fields and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that `DEFAULT` is a reserved word. Ideally, change your schema to avoid using reserved words as field names. Alternatively, quote the name:

```
UPDATE user_inventory SET `Default`=0 WHERE `Default`=1 AND UserID=@oid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try putting reserved SQL keywords in block brackets as per below

```
UPDATE user_inventory SET [Default]=0 WHERE [Default]=1 AND UserID=@oid
```